# How to debug dependency conflicts in Maven's own build classpath

Tags: java, maven

I just ran into a strange problem with Maven today. I ran into the following exception while running my unit tests:

```
java.lang.VerifyError: class com.google.debugging.sourcemap.proto.Mapping$OriginalMapping overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at com.google.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapConsumerV3.getOriginalMappingForEntry(SourceMapConsumerV3.java:533)
        at com.google.debugging.sourcemap.SourceMapConsumerV3.getMappingForLine(SourceMapConsumerV3.java:253)
        at org.stjs.generator.sourcemap.JavascriptToJava.getJavaLine(JavascriptToJava.java:46)
        at org.stjs.generator.sourcemap.JavascriptToJava.buildStacktraceElement(JavascriptToJava.java:107)
        at org.stjs.generator.sourcemap.JavascriptToJava.buildStacktrace(JavascriptToJava.java:147)
        at org.stjs.testing.driver.TestResult.buildException(TestResult.java:66)
        at org.stjs.testing.driver.TestResultCollection.buildException(TestResultCollection.java:64)
        at org.stjs.testing.driver.STJSTestDriverRunner$1.evaluate(STJSTestDriverRunner.java:74)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.stjs.testing.driver.STJSTestDriverRunner.run(STJSTestDriverRunner.java:46)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:264)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:124)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray2(ReflectionUtils.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:87)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:95)
```

Now I know that this kind of `VerifyError` is typically caused by a dependency conflict that has not been solved correctly. In this case, it seems that the version of the protobuf library on the classpath is not the expected one.

The interesting thing about this exception that makes it different from everything I've seen before, is that it doesn't happen in the classpath of the application under test, but it happens from within Maven's own classpath. I believe that I have a dependency conflict between two build plugins. Each plugin probably wants a different version of protobuf.

I know how to debug this kind of things when it happens in the project classpath, but **how can you debug this problem when it happens from within the build tool's own classpath?**

Comment: Have you checked your .m2/repository to see which protobuf version is downloaded and used when runnging your tests?

Comment: Wouldn't .m2/repository contain all the versions of protobuf that any of the projects I have ever built have ever depended on? Anyway, I have 2.4.1 and 2.5.0 there. It helps a bit, but I still need to know who imports 2.4.1 so I can fix my build.

Comment: just clean it before relaunching your test